# How to import Rails helpers in to the functional tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-3, functional-testing

Hi I recently inherited a project in which the former dev was not familiar with rails, and decided to put a lot of important logic into the view helpers.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  include SessionsHelper
  include BannersHelper
  include UsersHelper
  include EventsHelper
end
```

Specifically session management. This is okay and working with the app but I am having problems writing tests for this.

A specific example. Some of the actions do a `before_filter` to see if a `current_user` is an admin. This `current_user` is normally set by a `sessions_helper` method that is shared in all our controllers
So in order to properly test our controllers I need to be able to use this `current_user` method

I have tried this:

```
require 'test_helper'
require File.expand_path('../../../app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb', __FILE__)

class AppsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  setup do
    @app = apps(:one)
    current_user = users(:one)
  end

  test "should create app" do
    assert_difference('App.count') do
      post :create, :app => @app.attributes
  end
end
```

The require statement finds the `session_helper.rb` okay but without the Rails magic it is not accessible in the same way with in the `AppsControllerTest`

How can I spoof this crazy setup to test?

Comment: doing `include SessionsHelper` inside the `AppsControllerTest` class doesn't help? If you're going to be actively developing on this app I'd strongly recommend refactoring code written by them, that doesn't make sense, you'll be saving time. It sounds like you're just trying to keep it running though, and haven't the time to invest in that.

Comment: So it seems like the helpers are being included because the App controller calls a method in the user_helper that then fires an error in the sessions_helper. So it seems as though they are included but cannot talk with each other.z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution i found was to re-factor and use a decent auth plugin

Answer (score 1):

Why re-factor? You can very easily include helpers from your project in your tests. I did the following to do so.

```
require_relative '../../app/helpers/import_helper'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test helpers, you can follow the example here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#testing-helpers

```
class UserHelperTest < ActionView::TestCase
  include UserHelper       ########### <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

  test "should return the user name" do
    # ...
  end
end
```

This is for unit tests on individual methods. I think that if you want to test at a higher level, and you will be using multiple controllers w/redirects, you should use an integration test:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#integration-testing

As an example:

```
require 'test_helper'
 
class UserFlowsTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  fixtures :users
 
  test "login and browse site" do
    # login via https
    https!
    get "/login"
    assert_response :success
 
    post_via_redirect "/login", username: users(:david).username, password: users(:david).password
    assert_equal '/welcome', path
    assert_equal 'Welcome david!', flash[:notice]
 
    https!(false)
    get "/posts/all"
    assert_response :success
    assert assigns(:products)
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

To be able to use Devise in your tests, you should add

```
include Devise::TestHelpers
```

to each `ActionController::TestCase` instance. Then in the `setup` method you do

```
sign_in users(:one)
```

instead of

```
current_user = users(:one)
```

All your functional tests should work fine, then.

Comment: The Original question says that devise is not being used.

Comment: I assumed you where using Devise since the common `current_user` variable. By the way, you've never said that you were *not* using Devise. Sorry for the misunderstanding.