# Rails application. Rspec/capybara tests not accessing helper methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, capybara, integration-testing, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I have a rails application that is a Twitter clone. It has a User model and a Sessions model. I am writing integration tests for user pages and I am generating users using a factory (via FactoryGirl).

I am having trouble with a test not being able to run a method a helper method.

I get this error after `rspec spec/`:

```
UserPages FollowUnfollows Post to /relationships click Follow button
     Failure/Error: visit user_path(other_user)
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `following? for nil:NilClass
```

`spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb`:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "UserPages" do 
    describe "FollowUnfollows" do
        describe "Post to /relationships" do
            let (:other_user) {FactoryGirl.create(:user)}
            let (:user) {FactoryGirl.create(:user)}
            before do
                sign_in user
            end

            it "click Follow button" do
                visit user_path(other_user)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

I'm using a `spec/support/utilities.rb` file to sign users in:

```
include ApplicationHelper

def sign_in(user)
    visit signin_path
    fill_in "Username", with: user.username
    fill_in "Password", with: user.password
    click_button "Log In"
    cookies[:token] = user.token
end
```

I have a show page for another user that I have my user go to -- `views/users/show.html.erb` (abridged):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
            <div class="span3">
                <p><%= @user.username %></p>
                <% if @user == current_user %>
                    <%= render 'tweet_box' %>
                <% else %>
                    <% unless current_user.following?(@user) %>     
                        <%= render 'follow_button'  %>
                    <% else %>
                        <%= render 'unfollow_button' %>
                    <% end %>
                <% end %>
            </div>      
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then I have a helper that includes several important methods. It is included in the `ApplicationController` with `include SessionsHelper`. `app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb`:

```
module SessionsHelper
    def start_session(user)
        cookies.permanent[:token] = user.token
        self.current_user=user
    end
    def user_signed_in?
        !current_user.nil?
    end
    def current_user
        @current_user ||= User.find_by_token(cookies[:token])
    end
    def current_user=(user)
        @current_user=user
    end
    def end_session
        self.current_user=nil
        cookies.delete(:token)
    end
end
```

Anyone that has done Michael Hartl's tutorial will recognize a lot of this. I am trying to do this from memory, and I am also trying to write new tests and understand everything I do. That's why I am asking these questions. Any help or feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Your test would seem to be failing on the `<% unless current_user.following?(@user) %>` line in your **views/users/show.html.erb** file.  Does your `User` class have a `following?` method defined?

Comment: it did. I actually switched to using devise. `def following?(other_user)
    relationships.find_by_followed_id(other_user.id)
  end` was what I had in my user model `model.rb`

Comment: I would seem that's your issue then.  Have you tried re-instating the `following?` method on your devise `User` class?

Comment: No, I had the issue before I switched to Devise. This post helped me decide to do that. I had the same problems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160417/how-to-import-rails-helpers-in-to-the-functional-tests

Comment: Just realized also that since the error is `undefined method following? for nil:NilClass`, it would also seem that your `current_user` method is returning `nil`, so is there an issue with `User.find_by_token(cookies[:token])` not returning a user?

Comment: that is a good question. I would have to checkout old source with git and poke around to see if that's the case. I had a hunch that current_user was nil in the tests. The thing is, I'm sure that it was not nil when I checked it by clicking around in the browser. Only the tests were failing. That did leave me wondering what was going on with the cookies hash in my tests.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30921/discussion-between-david-west-and-paul-fioravanti)